# What is this "N with waves emanating" notification icon?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, notification-icons

Does anyone know what the symbol at the top of the screen between 'Bluetooth' and 'silent' is? The one that looks like an 'N' with waves emanating from it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be an **NFC tag notification**, looks like your device has support for NFC tags